# Recibir mensaje con GetMessage de tipo struct y asignarlo a una variable

Tags: c, windows, hilos, proceso

Ya he mandado el mensaje al hilo deseado a través de PostThreadMessage y en el parametro lparam paso la dirección de memoria de la estructura que quiero enviar:

```
PostThreadMessage( p->idHilo, WM_USER, 10 , (LPARAM)&estructura);
```

A la hora de recibir hago esto:

```
struct estructura *e;

while(GetMessage( &mensaje, NULL, WM_USER, WM_USER+2)){
    e  =  &mensaje.lParam;
    printf("%c\n",e->miCaracter);
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Pues que como se recibe bien en la estructura, ya que lo que he puesto, no imprime bien